# App Pool Recycle in IIS is changing file permissions on a DLL

Tags: .net, iis, dll, application-pool

I've never seen anything like this and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I have an app in IIS, and inside the `bin` folder I have a copy of `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll`.

When someone recycles the app pool or turns the website off and on again, the functionality of my application that uses `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll` starts throwing:

> `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.`

The DLL in question, sitting in the `bin` folder, does have full control given to the service account given to the app pool.

To "fix" this, I've found I can simply perform any write operation within the same `bin` folder - rename a folder, delete a file, rename any file. They all do ***something*** that, without changing the permissions (because I've compared them before and after) resolves the issue.

If I recycle the app pool again, the same `Access is denied` error returns.

So my questions are:

- What could be causing the `Access is denied` issue to begin with? Is the application not using the DLL in the bin folder that I'm expecting?
- What does recycling the app pool do to cause the DLL to revert to an `Access is denied` state? Is it pulling in an old/cached/broken version of the DLL from somewhere?
- Why does performing a file write operation in the `bin` folder fix this? What might IIS be doing behind-the-scenes when it monitors a change to the directory it is serving an application out of?

Comment: Try this - stop pool, delete temporary asp.net cache, start pool. See if same happens

Comment: Sorry @T.S. didn't see your comment, thanks for the suggestion- this did temporarily fix it, but in the same manner as modifying the bin folder did. The recycle still breaks the application again. I did the following a few times: 1) Stop the app pool 2) Delete all the app's temp folders 3) Start the app pool 4) Works! 5) Recycle app pool 6) Broken again :(     So I believe this is directly tied to something happening during an app pool recycle.

Comment: so, if it works then go with it. Do you need a cmd script for it?

Comment: The problem is that this server hosts quite a number of applications and represents a Test environment - so there's a lot of other devs from different teams often executing deploys which may issue app pool recycles or IIS resets (which also "break" the permissions on the DLL). So while I could schedule something like this, it's not ideal and may be overridden at any moment (break again) when deployment activities take place

Comment: your application should run in its specific pool and you shouldn't have an issue with stopping one pool. In other words, if someone recycles their pool, it shouldn't affect your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after this problem persisted to other environments, I needed to quickly resolve this issue.

John Wu's answer helped me track down the problem to the temporary IIS folders that IIS was spinning up, where the first new folder fresh from an IIS reset was broken, subsequent forced new temporary folders worked, but overtime those would be "corrupted".

Guessing that perhaps a virus scanner or other scheduled process on the computer (which is shared among many teams and many applications unfortunately) was picking the file up and locking it, I tried moving my temporary folder elsewhere by adding this to my `web.config`:

```
<compilation tempDirectory="D:\Inetpub\[path to my application in IIS]\Temporary Files">
```

`Temporary Files` is just the name I gave a new folder within my applications deployment location. After giving my AppPool service account permissions to this folder, my problems went away.

I didn't solve the problem of *what* was messing with my DLL, but I've come to accept that, being on a busy shared box, it might be unavoidable - and simply moved my applications temporary files out of the common default location and into a new app-specific location.

App Pool recycles stopped breaking my app, and it's been working all morning. If you have this issue and can't spend the time to figure out what is locking your files, moving them out into their own location might help.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, ASP.NET doesn't actually execute or link to the files in the `bin` folder.  Instead, it copies them to a temporary folder which looks something like this:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\VdirName\3906a747

Whenever you modify anything in the site (including the bin folder), ASP.NET creates a new temporary directory and copies the files there.  The new directory might look like this:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\VdirName\ **a9b6d973**

My guess is that some process had a lock on the DLL.  When you modified the contents of the bin folder, ASP.NET created a new temporary folder and copied the DLLs there.  The new folder didn't have the issue with the lock.

To find out who has the file locked, go to a command line and type this:

```
 tasklist /m Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll
```

Comment: I must have been brainfarting because I never even considered temporary folders, great point. I didn't know that modifying the bin folder would split it off into a new temporary instance though, so almost certainly doing an app-pool recycle is doing something to muck-up the currently served version of the DLL, and the "new" directory used after the bin modification is fine.

Comment: In the "working" state from yesterday it says w3wp.exe under my service-account is using the module. 1) I recycled the app pool, and with no requests, nothing is using the module after further tasklist calls. 2) I initiated a request, which now breaks with Access is Denied, and in-between requests, nothing is using the module when I call tasklist now. So it's in the broken state right now (Access is Denied) but nothing is using it in the tasklist. So I don't think it's a file lock, but I at least know something in the act of recycling the app pool is not working correctly.